# How can I modify this code to write to Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, arduino-esp8266

My problem is that when I send a post from an rfid card via esp8266, the data is an rfid number, but the data can't appear because the code I gave has not been written into Laravel.

This PHP code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['uid'])) {
        $uid = $_POST["uid"];
        $sql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "INSERT INTO tb_entry VALUES ('$uid')");
    }
?>
```

How can I write this code into Laravel controller?

Comment: What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: Note that this code contains a SQL injection vulnerability - do not use this code on a public server. It is not safe.

Comment: My problem is that when I send a post from an rfid card via esp8266, the data is an rfid number. but the data can't appear because the code I gave has not been written into laravel,

sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
if ($request->has('uid')) {
    DB::table('tb_entry')->insert([
        'uuid' => $request->uuid
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a controller: `php artisan make:controller MyController`
2. add a method to the controller like `public function test(Request $request) {}`
3. rewrite your code a little bit and pasted in:

```php
public function test(Request $request) {

    if (null !== $request->post('uid')) {
        $uid = $request->post('uid');
        // Note: you can use Laravel model instead plain mysqli query
        // ** Beware of SQL injection vulnerabilities! **
        $sql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "INSERT INTO tb_entry VALUES ('$uid')");
    }
}
```

Comment: the code has a problem, namely in the if isset part. The problem that appears is :

**Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)**